# Can we ensure elasticsearch call locally?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, information-retrieval

Suppose I have a service, and elasticsearch running on multiple hosts. If I ensure that each host contains the complete elasticsearch index (by having replicas >= numberOfHosts-1), is it possible to make sure that a service call on a particular host only searches in the index of the same host (i.e. no elasticsearch calls are made across hosts)?

Answer (score 1):

Using [shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html), you can ensure that shards of an index will only reside on a single host. Note, however, that by doing so, if you host goes down, you'll lose data.

```
PUT test/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.include._ip": "192.168.1.1",
  "index.routing.allocation.exclude._ip": "192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3"
}
```

As a result, if you query the `test` index directly on `192.168.1.1` you can be sure that there won't be any chatter between `192.168.1.1` and the nodes to fulfill your request.

If you send your query to a client node or another kind of load balancer node, your request is guaranteed to be routed directly to `192.168.1.1` since the cluster will be aware that the `test` index is only available on that host.

It is not a good practice to localize an index on a single host as if that host fails or gets corrupted, you're guaranteed to lose data.